# How could I use server.urlencode?

Tags: asp.net, system.web

I would like to call a function to insert url strings into my db, so I combine the url string with `server.urlencode`. I imported `system.web` at the beginning of this **.vb** program (**not aspx.vb**) but I still can not use `server.urlencode`. Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Welcome to one of the most exciting Q&A site on this planet. Add the code you have written in to your post for audiences to have a look. They will be able to help you better if they can see the code snippet as well along with what exact error/exception you are getting by your compiler or at run time.

Comment: Do you have `HttpContext` namespace? Can you try `HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode`?

Comment: I import system.web.httpcontext, and I could use HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode. But there's another error : "NullReferenceException was caught".